# what is a good functional language that can be mixed with C++?

Tags: c++, functional-programming

I would like to walk the path of functional languages, since i have started i have only used OO languages and multi-paradigm languages; in the last period of time i have focused myself on C++ and in my understanding functional languages shines when you need to keep a consistent state and they are often used by some mission-critical services like banking services.

I don not want to leave C++, I would like to try a mix, I'm also interested only in cross-platform solutions among x86, ARM and Linux, Windows and BSD/Mac, so i suppose that F# is out ( also it appears to be just the Microsoft version of Ocaml for what i have read).

Can you suggest a language that will be good for this mix and clarify where and when a functional language can really offer the most ?

Comment: C++, mired in its history with C, doesn't mix with functional languages.

Comment: get some idea from [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780316/easiest-way-to-build-a-cross-platform-application) and [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385229/whats-the-most-cross-platform-friendly-coding-language)

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams oh, c'mon, there must be something that i can do about that, the world is based on C and C++, even the virtual machines that runs all this "modern" languages like Java, Python and C# have their roots in the C/C++ world.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan the only name in there is Lua ... are you suggesting Lua ?

Comment: If you believe that then you don't understand how functional programming languages work.

Comment: F# is cross-platform via Mono (Linux, Max, Windows at least). Also, it has long since evolved away from OCaml, and boasts many unique features of its own.

Comment: Cats and dogs have been known to get along, they'll forever post videos of it on YouTube.  Reaching for a similar paradigm to compare a functional language to C++, no, I don't have any cutesy links for that.  Short from the drastically different way to write code, they fundamentally don't even manage *memory* the same way, how could that ever turn out to be cute?

Comment: @user1824407 What do you mean by "mix"? Are you interested in interoperating at an API level?

Comment: Nominating this for reopen. The reason given for it being closed does not actually describe the question. This isn't a subjective question that will lead to debate or discussion. If there aren't any languages that meet the criteria in the question, then that's the answer.

Comment: Since languages like Haskell and Mercury have C interfaces allowing cross-language calls in either direction, you clearly can combine functional languages and C++ (via C). So I don't know why Ignacio and Hans seem to be saying that the concept doesn't even make sense. I wouldn't *want* to use such features unless I had to move performance critical code to C or I needed to interface with existing libraries written in languages callable from C, but you *can* do it.

Comment: Do have a look at Felix: http://felix-lang.org/ "It is a C++ code generator and thereby can provide compatibility with existing C and C++ code bases. We let the native C++ compiler do the hard work of low level optimisation whilst Felix does high level optimisations. [...] However Felix has its own type system based on a combination of Ocaml and Haskell. Like Ocaml it provides strong support for functional programming, whilst also supporting imperative programming. The type system is strict."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use C++11 lambda functions and expressions ;)

Comment: Don't forget `constexpr` which allows compiler-enforced pure functions.

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in a language which is similar to C++ (with good C/C++ interoperability, too), but has powerful constructs from functional languages, you might like [Rust](http://rust-lang.org). One of the Rust developers wrote up a [comparison of Rust's and C++'s goals](http://pcwalton.blogspot.com/2010/12/c-design-goals-in-context-of-rust.html), which you might find informative.

Support for ARM [does not yet exist](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues/1858), but Rust is LLVM-based, and LLVM supports ARM, so it's certainly possible to do.